# It's possible to get/set the width of a character?

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to have the width of each character in my text area, can be by setting or getting.

```
                   <Field
                        style={{
                           width: "60ch",
                           height: "300px",
                           fontFamily: '"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace',
                           fontSize: "14px",
                        }}
                        as='textarea'
                        id='text'
                        name='text'
                        type='text'
                        label='Text'
                     />
```

I've tried to set a `span` with the same font-size and font-family to get it, and so I'd calculate the numbers of characters in each row.

```
                     <span
                        style={{
                           position: "absolute",
                           top: "-100px",
                           fontFamily: '"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace',
                           fontSize: "14px",
                        }}
                        id='span'
                     >
                        b
                     </span>
```

But doing the calculations bellow, it doesn't work even for the default width (I settled as 60ch, so each line would be 60 characters). The result I have is that each row should have 63.125 characters, which is wrong.

```
   document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
      let textarea: any = document.querySelector("#text");
      let width = getComputedStyle(textarea).width;
      let height = getComputedStyle(textarea).height;
      console.log(width, height);

      let span: any = document.querySelector("#span");
      let spanWidth = getComputedStyle(span).width;
      console.log('SPAN WIDTH',spanWidth)
      console.log('PER LINE', (parseInt(width.slice(0,-2))/parseInt(spanWidth.slice(0,-2))))
```

Comment: I’m not too sure what it is you want as if you use a non fixed size font the number of characters you can get in a fixed width will vary depending on the text and conversely  the width of a text of 60 characters will vary. Could you clarify what you want to measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use parseInt() for this matter, at least not at first.
You first need to divide the numbers as a float (parseFloat()) and then you can round the result, but if you round it using parseInt first you'll have a precision problem.

Also, pay attention to the element's default padding, which can affect your calculations.